# How to Get ID using SmartCardProvisioning.GetIdAsync (Windows.Device.SmartCards)

Tags: c#, smartcard, windows-8.1

Windows 8.1 has brought up a new [SmartCards API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.smartcards.aspx) and I am currently using ACR122U-49 Smart Card Reader and luckily it is able to read the cards from my application (and the [sample app](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Smart-card-sample-c7d342e0) of Windows SDK) as well.

Now the problem is, I want to get the Smart Card's ID ([using GetIdAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.smartcards.smartcardprovisioning.aspx)) and it throws me an exception whenever I call it.

My code snippet:

```
async void reader_CardAdded(SmartCardReader sender, CardAddedEventArgs args)
    {
        SmartCardProvisioning provision =  await SmartCardProvisioning.FromSmartCardAsync(args.SmartCard);
        Guid cardID = await provision.GetIdAsync();
        var card = await args.SmartCard.GetAnswerToResetAsync();
    }
```

Exception I get upon calling second line of my function;

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>           Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

Please let me know how can I resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I resolved the above issue by mocking up existing Smart Card framework and making it possible for WinRT. https://smartcardswinrt.codeplex.com/